# Regex to select column names from SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, character

I have a regexp that selects the columns from SQL query: `\bwf\.[^,|^\s|^)]*`

So from both queries

```
SELECT (wf.Name,
       wf.Status)

SELECT wf.Name, wf.Status
```

it will return *"wf.Name"*, *"wf.Status"*. But also I want to cover case when column contains round brackets:

```
SELECT (wf.Name,
       wf.Status())
```

regexp should return *"wf.Name"*, *"wf.Status()"*.

I tried to do it through non-capturing group `(?:(?!\s|,|<statement>).)*` but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\bwf(?:\.\w+)+(?:\(\))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJp5PF/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `wf` - a `wf` string
- `(?:\.\w+)+` - one or more repetitions of a `.` and one or more word chars
  `(?:\(\))?` - an optional occurrence of a `()` substring.